# How to create a condition to hide and show a video in Angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, if-statement, conditional-statements

In our homepage we have a video presentation. I would like to know know how to replicate this video in every product page which contains a video, if the product hasn't a video the video should be hidden.

Comment: What did you try, show some code. This seems like a basic case of not knowing how to use shared components and leveraging ngIf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Create an condition you can use the *ngIf directive and provide your condition in your HTML page.
Here I have provided a sample code for your reference

HTML:

```
<div class="container" style="max-width: 550px">
    <h2 class="text-center mb-5">Angular Login with Google</h2>
  
    <div *ngIf="isVideo === false">
      <p>No Video found</p>
    </div>
  
    <div *ngIf="isVideo === true">
      <video width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     </video>
  </div>
```

Method in component.ts:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.Service.getvideos.subscribe((videoid) => {
      this.isVideo = (videoid != null);
      
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `*ngIf` statement on the container of your video with the condition of if the product has a video.